# Timeout to clear flash message in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to give timeout to clear my `FlashService` message. But it works as delay time.

```
FlashService.Success(("Removed Successfully"), false);
```

In this I am using false as condition. It means when page or location changed flash message gets cleared.

My **flash.service.js**

```
function clearFlashMessage() {
                var flash = $rootScope.flash;
                if (flash) {
                    if (!flash.keepAfterLocationChange) {
                        delete $rootScope.flash;
                    } else {
                        // only keep for a single location change
                        flash.keepAfterLocationChange = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function Success(message, keepAfterLocationChange) {
            $rootScope.flash = {
                message: message,
                type: 'success', 
                keepAfterLocationChange: keepAfterLocationChange
            };
        }

        function Error(message, keepAfterLocationChange) {
            $rootScope.flash = {
                message: message,
                type: 'error',
                keepAfterLocationChange: keepAfterLocationChange
            };
        }
```

In my above js I am clearing the flash message with flag as "false" when page or location changed.

I need to set the timeout in that false condition. That is if flag is false then flash message need to be cleared within some time period.

Comment: That's just delaying showing the message, you would need to make changes in the service for that I guess

Comment: it shows after 2000ms because you have given the delay of 2000ms. isnt this you want?

Comment: it is how $timeout works. It resolves the function after the given delay. I guess you have to exit that FlashService after 2000 ms ..then you have to do some work around

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function to clear the message after 2 sec - instead of doing `$timeout(fn, interval)`.
i.e.

```
FlashService.Success(("Removed Successfully"), false);
$timeout(function(){
   //clear message
   //FlashService.ClearMessage(); - or whatever how you clear the message
}, 2000);
```

Comment: It clears only success message. But the div is visible.    As above in my edited code.

Comment: @kalai: You need to show you `div` html to get answers accordingly... Also, showing how `FlashService` displays the message will help.

Comment: @kalai: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please view my updated code above. I am using a seperate flash.service.js  and calling same function whenever needed.

Answer (score -1):

You need delete $rootScope.flash after delay. The simpliest way is to start another function called in functions Error and Success. Don't forget to inject $timeout :)

(function () {
    'use strict';

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('FlashService', FlashService);

FlashService.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$timeout'];
function FlashService($rootScope, $timeout) {
    var service = {};

    service.Success = Success;
    service.Error = Error;

    initService();

    return service;

    function initService() {
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function () {
            clearFlashMessage();
        });

        function clearFlashMessage() {
            var flash = $rootScope.flash;
            if (flash) {
                if (!flash.keepAfterLocationChange) {
                    delete $rootScope.flash;
                } else {
                    // only keep for a single location change
                    flash.keepAfterLocationChange = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function clearFlashMessageT() {
        console.log("clear after 2 sec started")
        $timeout(function(){
            delete $rootScope.flash;
         }, 2000);
    }

    function Success(message, keepAfterLocationChange) {
        $rootScope.flash = {
            message: message,
            type: 'success', 
            keepAfterLocationChange: keepAfterLocationChange
        };
    clearFlashMessageT()
    }

    function Error(message, keepAfterLocationChange) {
        $rootScope.flash = {
            message: message,
            type: 'error',
            keepAfterLocationChange: keepAfterLocationChange
        };
    clearFlashMessageT()
    }
}
```

})();